# Pandas merge two rows with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder if there is a way to groupby rows then conditional aggregate groups. Thank you 
for example, 
for colA is A, it should set colB for second A to test1 and sum colC

```
colA colB colC
A   test1  5
A   None   6
B   test1  4
C   test1  5
C   test3  4
D   test4  5
D   None   4
```

expected result

```
colA colB colC
A   test1  11
B   test1  4
C   test1  5
C   test3  4
D   test4  9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, You can used groupby and fill and then again group and sum

```
df['colB'] = df.groupby('colA').colB.ffill().bfill()
df.groupby(['colA','colB'], as_index = False).sum()

    colA    colB    colC
0   A       test1   11
1   B       test1   4
2   C       test1   5
3   C       test3   4
4   D       test4   9
```

Comment: it will only fill the cell if there is a data before it. if the order is not as I posted, it wouldn't work. Thank you

Comment: @galaxyan, you can user ffill().bfill(). Pl see the edit